# Adding a space in the beginning and end of every line using regular expressions

Tags: regex, adobe-brackets

As the title suggests I need a space character at the beginning and end of each line in a text document.

Here is an excerpt from the text:

```
56
00:04:28.620 --> 00:04:32.070
and a little sturdier sounding, but it
also alters the articulation of it.

57
00:04:32.070 --> 00:04:35.310
So that's what's kind of cool about
parallel compression, you kind of beat

58
00:04:35.310 --> 00:04:39.790
something up a little bit and blend it in,
and you get the best of both worlds.
```

I am using Brackets (OSX) and was hoping someone could help me with finding a regular expression that could be used in the find & replace function, but of course, any better suggestions are welcome!

Reason:
I am preparing this large corpus of transcripts (+100000 lines) for text analysis and need to prepare it prior to feeding into an analyzer in MATLAB.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the quick reply! I've tried the expression you suggested, but brackets does not seem to be happy with it and upon entering: ^(?=\S)|(?<=\S)$ it returns: 'Invalid regular expression: /^(?=\S)|(?<=\S)$/: Invalid group. When I tried ^(?=\S) it successfully found and replaced the beginning of each line. I've tried using just: (?<=\S)$ but it says 'invalid group'. Please let me know, thank you, Joe

Answer (score 1):

With lookarounds you can search for these positions:

```
^(?=\S)|(?<=\S)$
```

These positions need to be replaced by `\`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vZS0sp/1/).

---

Broken down:

```
^(?=\S)  # ^ = start of line (multiline mode) 
         # plus making sure there's no whitespace immediately ahead
|        # or
(?<=\S)$ # pos. lookbehind and end of string/line
```